# Python- Getting link of new webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium and I wrote this code that gets user input and searches in ebay but I want to save the new link of the search so I can pass it on to BeautifulSoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

search_ = input()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Leila\Downloads\chromedriver_win32')
browser.get("https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2499334.m570.l1311.R1.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xphones.TRS0&_nkw=phones&_sacat=0")
Search = browser.find_element_by_id('kw')
Search.send_keys(search_)
Search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#how do you write a code that gets the link of the new page it loads
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract a link from a webpage, you need to make use of the `HREF` attribute and use the `get_attribute()` method.

This example from [here](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-get-links/) illustrates how it would work.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.w3.org/')
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

In your case, do:

```
Search = browser.find_element_by_id('kw')
page_link = Search.get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: thankyou. Are the code on top with the 'options' necessary?